# What is the sign convention in determining magnetic inclination in northern hemisphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, conventions, geomagnetism

I am finding a  problem in understanding the sign convention associated with measuring the dip angle (Magnetic Inclination) in southern and northern hemisphere.
I have tried to consult this matter on several books and found contradictory text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the dip (inclination) is positive downwards (into the Earth) and negative upwards. See, for example, [this page](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/faqgeom.shtml#What_are_the_magnetic_elements) from the National Centers for Environmental Information and [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=nzJLiPjHvCQC&pg=PA140&dq=magnetic%20inclination&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib8ZCfycbiAhUD658KHTpUATUQ6AEIYDAJ#v=onepage&q=magnetic%20inclination&f=false). (I wonder what books you read - I have never seen it defined any other way.) Since the Earth's field dips down in the northern hemisphere, its inclination is positive; and in the southern hemisphere, it is inclined upwards (negative).

Answer (score 0):

Angle of dip in northern hemisphere  is taken as positive and in southern hemisphere it is taken as negative

Comment: Shabnam, welcome to the StackExchange. Please keep in mind that adding sources is recommended.